Serial port from Arduino to PC noise
I am trying to connect a on-off switch to an Arduino board, then connect the Arduino board to my PC through the serial port with the baud rate of 9600. The idea is that when the switch is off, a previously saved video on my PC plays. When, the switch is pressed to the on position, a second video plays on top of the first video which has been playing.
The problem that I face is that when I press the switch, the second video blinks, as in it appears and disappears, indicating that the signal on the serial port fluctuates between 0 and 1 (perhaps in the form of pulses). The solution/hack that I came up with was to apply an exponentially decaying moving average filter on the serial input. It kind of fixes the problem with proper moving average length and threshold values, but it creates a few seconds of delay in stopping the video when I don't press the switch.
Any better idea/solution?
This is the Arduino code used to program the Arduino board. The switch is connected to the Ground and pin 2:
/*
Input Pull-up Serial

This example demonstrates the use of pinMode(INPUT_PULLUP). It reads a digital
input on pin 2 and prints the results to the Serial Monitor.

The circuit:
  - momentary switch attached from pin 2 to ground
  - built-in LED on pin 13

Unlike pinMode(INPUT), there is no pull-down resistor necessary. An internal
20K-ohm resistor is pulled to 5V. This configuration causes the input to read
HIGH when the switch is open, and LOW when it is closed.


This example code is in the public domain.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/InputPullupSerial
*/

void setup() 
{
  //start serial connection
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //configure pin 2 as an input and enable the internal pull-up resistor
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  //read the pushbutton value into a variable
  int sensorVal = digitalRead(2);
  //print out the value of the pushbutton
  Serial.println(sensorVal);

  // Keep in mind the pull-up means the pushbutton's logic is inverted. It goes
  // HIGH when it's open, and LOW when it's pressed. Turn on pin 13 when the
  // button's pressed, and off when it's not:
  if (sensorVal == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
}

This is the Processing code to read the serial input from Arduino and display the two videos on top of one another:
import processing.video.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // The serial port

boolean PlaySecondMovie = false;

final int MovingAvgLength = 50;
float MovingAvg = 0;
final float MovingAvgThreshold = 0.002;

final int NumMovies = 2;
Movie mymovies[] = new Movie[NumMovies];

/*void keyPressed() 
{
  if (key == 'a') 
  {
    PlaySecondMovie=!PlaySecondMovie;
    //mymovies[1].resume();
  }
}*/


void setup() 
{
  // List all the available serial ports:
  printArray(Serial.list());
  // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  
  size(640, 480);

  mymovies[0] = new Movie(this, "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Shiraz/2 films/2.mp4");
  mymovies[0].loop();
  mymovies[1] = new Movie(this, "/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/Shiraz/2 films/1.mp4");
  mymovies[1].loop();
  //mymovies[1].stop();
}

float approxMovingAverage (float avg, float new_sample, int N) 
{
    avg -= avg / N;
    avg += new_sample / N;
    return avg;
}


/*int calcAvg(Vector)
{
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i: MovingWindow)  sum += i;
  float avg = sum/MovingWindow.length;
  if (avg > 0.5)
    return(1);
  else
    return(0);
}*/



// Step 4. Read new frames from the movie.
void movieEvent(Movie mymovies) 
{
  mymovies.read();
}

// Step 5. Display movie.
void draw() 
{
  while (myPort.available() > 0) 
  {
    String inBuffer = myPort.readString();   
    if (inBuffer != null) 
    {
      inBuffer = trim(inBuffer);
      println(inBuffer);
      if ("0".equals(inBuffer))
      {
        MovingAvg = approxMovingAverage (MovingAvg, 1, MovingAvgLength);      
      }
      else
      {
        MovingAvg = approxMovingAverage (MovingAvg, 0, MovingAvgLength);
      }
      println(MovingAvg);
    }
  }
  
  if (MovingAvg > MovingAvgThreshold) 
    PlaySecondMovie = true;
  else
    PlaySecondMovie = false;
  
  background(0);
  image(mymovies[0], 0, 0, width, height);
  if (PlaySecondMovie) 
  {
    image(mymovies[1], width/2, 0, width/2, height/2);
    mymovies[1].loop();
  }
  else
  {
    mymovies[1].pause();
  }
  //image(m[2], width/4, height/2, 3*width/4.0, height);
}

    

/*void keyPressed() {
  int keyIndex = -1;
  if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') {
    keyIndex = key - 'A';
  } else if (key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') {
    keyIndex = key - 'a';
  }
  if (keyIndex == -1) {
    // If it's not a letter key, clear the screen
    background(0);
  } else { 
    // It's a letter key, fill a rectangle
    fill(millis() % 255);
    float x = map(keyIndex, 0, 25, 0, width - rectWidth);
    rect(x, 0, rectWidth, height);
  }
}*/


"The solution/hack that I came up with was to apply an exponentially decaying moving average filter on the serial input" - You're applying the "filter" to the wrong "input". As @W.Holzke points out in his answer, the filtering needs to be applied to the reading of the switch/GPIO. This also distributes the processing load more ideally: the Arduino handles the raw switch input, filter/processes the input, and then transmits a clean command to the PC. IOW process & reduce the data as close as possible to its source.

Any better idea/suggestion? Read A Guide to Debouncing by Jack Gansselle

If you have a hardware switch, then it can bounce. So if you detect the change of the switch on the Arduino, wait for a given time, e.g. try 10ms, and read the input again to confirm the change. Then you should not have a delay on the PC side.
You could also read the values from the input into an array with a fixed sample rate and compare this array with all zeros or all ones. There are also integrated circuits which can prevent a switch from bouncing or give a debounced signal, but I think the software solution should do it.

I think the filtering is only necessary, if there is noise on the input signal. Otherwise you could check with an oscilloscope how long the switch is bouncing and add simply an appropriate delay, before you sample the input again.
